# Get the right method from a parsed string with reflection

Tags: java, parsing, reflection

I've made a generic class that take an Object as input and implements a method that given the string representation of one of that object's methods and its parameters ( ie, "charAt(3)"), make the parse and find and rub the right method.
I was able to make it run for the method that have no parameter but for reason that I don't understand keeps failing on some of the other that take them(like charAt for strings).
Here's the code.

```
public class MiniInterpreter<T> 
{
private Class<?> objClass;
private T object;

public MiniInterprete(T object)
{
    objClass = object.getClass();
    this.object = object;
}

private static boolean isNumeric(String str)  
{  
  try  
  {  
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    int i = Integer.parseInt(str);  
  }  
  catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
  {  
    return false;  
  }  
  return true;  
}

private static boolean isBoolean(String str)
{
    return (str.equalsIgnoreCase("true") || str.equalsIgnoreCase("false"));
}


private static boolean isDouble(String str)
{
    try
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        double d = Double.parseDouble(str);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public String getName(int index, String str)
{
    if(str.charAt(index) == '(' || str.charAt(index) == ')')
        return "";
    else
        return str.charAt(index) + getName(index + 1, str);
}

public String getParameters(int index, String str)
{
        switch(str.charAt(index))
        {
        case '(': return "" + getName(index + 1, str);
        default: return getParametri(index + 1, str);
        }
}

public Object parse(String method) throws GenericErrorException
{
    String name = getName(0,method);
    String parameters = getParameters(0,method);

    if(!parameters.equals(""))
    {
        return parseParameters(name, parameters.split(","));
    }

    Method m = null;

    try 
    {
        m = objClass.getMethod(name);
    } 
    catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {e.printStackTrace();} 
    catch (SecurityException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    try 
    {
        return m.invoke(object);
    } 
    catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {throw new GenericErrorException();}

}

private Object parseParameters(String name, String[] parameters) throws GenericErrorException
{
    List<Class<?>> parametersList = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
    List<Object> parametersArray = new ArrayList<Object>();

    for(String s : parameters)
    {
        Object obj = null;

        if(isNumeric(s))
        {
            obj = Integer.parseInt(s);
        }
        else if(isDouble(s))
        {
            obj = Double.parseDouble(s);
        }
        else if(isBoolean(s))
        {
            obj = Boolean.parseBoolean(s);
        }
        else
            obj = s;

        parametersList.add(obj.getClass());
        parametersArray.add(obj);
    }

    Method m = null;
    Class<?>[] parametersTypeArray = parametersList.toArray(new Class<?>[parametersList.size()]);

    try 
    {
            m = objClass.getMethod(name, parametersTypeArray );
    } 
    catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    try 
    {

        return m.invoke(object, parametersArray.toArray());
    } 
    catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
            | InvocationTargetException e) {throw new GenericErrorException();}

}

}
```

The only types admitted are String,Integer,Boolean and Double, that it's also true for the method to find, I have also to pretend that there isn't more than one method with that name and parameters, I was just curious to know if I did overlook something or if the code doesn't work right because of this limitation.
When it doesn't work I get the noSuchMethod exception and, of course, the nullPointer one cause it doesn't initialize the Method.

Comment: Can you post an actual string and actual method signature that you're using that are failing? Keep in mind that int and Integer are different method signatures.

Comment: m = objClass.getMethod(name, parametersTypeArray ); this is the line that generate the error, it's in parseParameters a private method invoked when the input string does not have parameters in the method(like length)

Answer (score 0):

As user1676075 suggests, your problem is that you're looking for a method that doesn't exist because you have the signature wrong.

`String#charAt(int)` is the example you give.  The signature is the primitive type `int` which is not the same as the class `Integer`.  You're using

```
obj = Integer.parseInt(s)
```

which returns an `int` type, so you probably think that you're getting a primitive.  But you can't store primitives in objects and Java knows this.  Since `obj` is an `Object`, Java auto-boxes your primitive `int` into an `Integer`.  Then you ask for a method with name `charAt` and signature `Integer` and the JRE says it's never heard of it.

If you're content to *only* work with methods that take `int` and ignore any method that takes an `Integer` (which will cover most of the standard library), you can just specify the type:

```
obj = Integer.parseInt(s);
parametersList.add(Integer.TYPE);  // the type of primitive ints
```

If, however, you want to do it correctly, you'll need to make your code more complex.  Rather than calling `Class#getMethod()`, I'd call `Class#getDeclaredMethods()`, find the subset of those that have the name you're looking for, and then see if the parameter list of the method is type-compatible with your parameters.

Comment: Let me see if I get it, auto boxing/unboxing let charAt(Integer) be runnable, but in reality does not exist a method with that signature so the search fail and I get the error. In that case even using DeclaredMethod the error will keep presenting it self, in fact I've even modified the code to get all the possible methods for that class, search the right one by name only and running it with invoke and, obviously, failed. If that is the case, there is nothing wrong with the code considered the premises that that have been given to me.

Comment: On making it runnable how about changing the parsing from i.e. Integer to int.class, that would give me the right parameters or not?

Comment: Auto-boxing means that Java will implicitly convert *instances* of primitives and their corresponding Objects.  `charAt(new Integer(5))` is implicitly converted into `charAt((new Integer(5)).intValue())`.  No such conversion exists for converting a `Integer.class` into a `Integer.TYPE`.

Comment: Yes that was exatly what I meant what I'm asking is that if I give the int,char,double.class to getMethod I will get the same error or it will work because the Class object is the right one.

Comment: `double.class` is not valid Java syntax.  I can't tell if you're using that as shorthand for `Double.TYPE` or misunderstanding the syntax.  Primitives are not classes, so they have no members or fields.  That's what makes them weird and forces you to write all kinds of special-case code to deal with them.

Comment: Yes it is, primitives don't have methods to call to see what class they are, so if you whant to get a class object from them you have to do like this, Class<?> c = double.class, the class field(it's really a keyword) works on types too and can be used in place of getClass() on the instances like this, c = HashSet.class.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the .class fix the program run smooth on all public methods, the error was in the private method parseParameters, it's not even really necessary to make a second method for the two distinct situation(parsing a string with parameters or empty ()), giving an empty list to getMethod will get you the right result anyway, thanks for your support.

```
for(String s : parameters)
    {

        if(isNumeric(s))
        {
            parametersList.add(int.class);
            parametersArray.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
        }
        else if(isDouble(s))
        {
            parametersList.add(double.class);
            parametersArray.add(Double.parseDouble(s));
        }
        else if(isBoolean(s))
        {
            parametersList.add(boolean.class);
            parametersArray.add(Boolean.parseBoolean(s));
        }
        else
        {
            parametersList.add(s.getClass());
            parametersArray.add(s);
        }
```